# Euclidean metric vs Taxicab Metric in R2

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

I am wondering when can the Taxicab metric be less than the Euclidean metric.

I am aware that usually the Taxicab metric > Euclidean metric and it would be the same if the 2 set of points are in the same vertical or horizontal line. But how can we introduce a constant C such that Taxicab metric < C * Euclidean metric.

Perhaps some reasoning for why C was chosen would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should add a picture with two points $P_1(x_1, y_1)$ and $P_2(x_2, y_2)$ and Show is there the Eukllidean and the Taxi metric.

Comment: Pythagoras' Theorem suggests a constant.